# How to check, if a HTML5 input is supported?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to check in my website, if the visitors browser support a HTML5 input type. How should I do it?

Comment: Check out the JS library @ http://www.modernizr.com/

Answer (score 26, accepted):

With the form fields you can use this:

```
var i = document.createElement("input");
i.setAttribute("type", "color");
return i.type !== "text";
```

If color is supported, i.type will be color but if it's not supported, the navigator returns text as default.
So a simple verification like this can help you.

Answer (score 13):

[Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/docs/#features-html5) has support for checking the new input types.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
function IsAttributeSupported(tagName, attrName) {
    var val = false;
    // Create element
    var input = document.createElement(tagName);
    // Check if attribute (attrName)
    // attribute exists
    if (attrName in input) {
        val = true;
    }
    // Delete "input" variable to
    // clear up its resources
    delete input;
    // Return detected value
    return val;
}

if (!IsAttributeSupported("input", "placeholder")) {
    // Do something special here
    alert("placeholder attribute is not supported");
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: +1 but `delete input` has no effect. You can only use `delete` to remove properties in an object.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, which is whether a specific input `type` is supported, not some attribute like `placeholder`.

Answer (score 0):

i would comment on the accepted answer, but won't allow me without a certain reputation, so i'll do it this way. if a browser runs into an input type it doesn't recognize, it will automatically default to a 'text' input itself. so I would say the JS in the answer is unnecessary (unless you want to default to something other than 'text')