# Trying to retire jquery-migrate

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, jquery-migrate

Currently I am using `$.browser.webkit` and `$.browser.msie` because the input types between the browsers have plenty of unique UI differences that I am having to accommodate for.

Specifically: Chrome changes my range to a slider, IE doesn't; and I have to place a spinner on the IE time type, Chrome covers that. There are others, but these are the ones that I have to deal with the most.

What is the preferred way to test for these differences rather than using the migrate lib's browser test? 
(I know I could query the useragent directly, but I would rather query the UI to see if I need to add a spinner, or slider, etc.)

Comment: If you want to test the availability of html5 elements, create an input in memory of type date and test if it is a date or a text field. This is a FAQ

Comment: The field is showing up as available, but they render completely differently. It is the rendering issue that I want to resolve.

Comment: It is the features of the elements that I am trying to figure out how to test for.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check, if a HTML5 input is supported?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8278670/how-to-check-if-a-html5-input-is-supported)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, [mplungjan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/295783/mplungjan) had an answer that was close but not what I needed. If you look at IE11 vs Chrome where both have a feature that is supported, you may see where they render the support completely differently. So my solution ended up being stay with the migrate lib to detect browser and version, then have my code override the render on browsers that need it.

This means that I will be keeping a dictionary of browsers and implemented features, so my code can intelligently override as dictionary dictates.

As for the case where a feature isn't supported, I will just continue to use the standard test for feature, that has worked and [mplungjan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/295783/mplungjan) has linked to one of the easiest ways to test. Not the best, but the easiest.

Switching to Twitter Bootstrap and Angular.JS UI has reduced some of this oddness, by using other peoples solutions.

Comment: You should not rely on browser detection. One thing I do not understand. If you already have a working spinner, slider, etc., why not simply use those? I mean in every browser. You do not need to detect anything.

Comment: The issue is that each browser renders the UI differently. CSS only goes so far. To overcome the UI differences and browser compatibility, I have gone as far as I can with Modernizr's capability detection. So now I am at a point where things that just don't work right, I built a compat lib, and overcome the shortcomings with the lib. However, this is all old, since then, I dumped the whole thing and went with Twitter Bootstrap + Angular.js for the frontend.