# How to set options for spectrum js in case of fallback from color type input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, spectrumjs

I am using the Spectrum JS as a fallback for browsers that does not support `<input type="color>`. To do so, just include the Spectrum JS library and everything is done automatically.

http://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/#modes-input

A working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/ctkY3/5542/

You should see the default color input box except when using IE. (Yes, even IE11 doesn't support color input. MS only support color input in Edge)

The problem is that once using the `$(element).spectrum()` function, it will show the spectrum color picker for all browser, while I just want to use it as a fallback. So, how can I add options to the fallback color picker?

Comment: Could you elaborate more on the last part of your post, please? What do you mean with "once using the `$(element).spectrum()`"? Also, what is the difference between what you need and the example you provided? Just as you told, in that example it will use spectrum only as a fallback, showing the default color picker in browsers that allow it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before calling `spectrum` on your jQuery object, you should check if the dom is ready and also if the browser supports color input.

Just as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8278718/370798) shows, when an input is not supported, it will default to text.

So, assuming you have an input with id `picker`, you can try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var i, colorInputSupported;
    i = document.createElement("input");
    i.setAttribute("type", "color");
    colorInputSupported = i.type !== "text";

    if(!colorInputSupported){
      $("#picker").spectrum({
        // Here you put the options
        color: "#f00"
      });
    }
});
```

Here is a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/7mwb4q1d/) of this code.

As an alternative, spectrum supports setting the options of the picker in the HTML element itself, via `data` attributes. For instance:

```
<input type='color' id="picker" data-color="#f00"/>
```

Will generate a color picker starting in red color, which will be displayed only in browsers that do not support the default color picker.

Here is a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/hfu89b65/). For a complete list of options, you can check them in [spectrums docs](http://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/#options)

Comment: Actually, I am not calling the function...... if you take a look at the documentation of spectrum.js, once you include the library js file,  it automatically replace color input when the browser doesn't support it. So, there is no "Before calling the function"

Comment: So, what do you mean with "once using `$(element).spectrum()` ?

Comment: I thought it was quite clear? It means I didn't use `$(element).spectrum`, as I want to use the default color input for browsers that support it. The library will automatically include the color picker once it detects the browser doesn't support it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I'm understanding your problem. As I see it, if it displays the color picker only in those browsers that do not support the default one, then it is already working as a fallback.

Comment: It works as a fallback, but the problem is that I am not able to pass the option variables as the function is not called by me.

Comment: I've edited my answer. I think that what you were missing was to call `$(element).spectrum` after the dom is loaded. Specifically, what you want is to call it after `spectrum.js` has run.

Comment: Alright..... I will count that as a workaround.... but I am still looking for a method to directly pass options to the library without having to do the checking myself.

Comment: @cytsunny I've added another pure-HTML alternative to my answer. Anyway, I think there is nothing wrong with making the check yourself via javascript.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with making the check myself, and I am already doing that before I ask the question. I am just asking to see if there are cleaner ways to solve the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135820/discussion-between-sam-and-cytsunny).

Comment: Maybe a better example will be `data-show-input`, a more obvious change and show how to handle two words option. But this is good enough to be marked as correct.